# Google Contacts: Missing Fields

Tags: python, google-plus, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to obtain a person's Google Contacts information using the Contacts v3 SDK, using Python with OAuth.

I obtain a XML feed with the person's contacts. However, I can only obtain the person's name and email.

I know there is additional information on a person's Google Contacts page when I view it in the GMail interface - addresses, blog URLs, phone numbers. I also use multiple contact importing apps for my cell phone which access these extra fields.

How do I go about accessing these extra fields?

Answer (score 0):

use this url to get full contect info

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
```

and python client.

```
      def retrieve_contact(gd_client):
          contact =gd_client.GetContact('https://www.google.com/m8/
                   feeds/contacts/default/full/contactId')
          # Do something with the contact.
          return contact
```

Request:

```
GET /m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
Response:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8; type=feed


...
```

[Click to more](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/)